# Permission error when creating a conda environment from a Docker container

Tags: docker, conda

I created a Docker image with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7

COPY . /home/latplan

RUN sudo apt-get update

RUN sudo apt-get install nano
```

Then, I run the corresponding container, and go within it, and I run

```
# bash
test_user@dda78566: cd /home/latplan
test_user@d582108a0756:/home/latplan$ conda env create --name latplan -f environment.yml
```

But I then get this error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/latplan/condaenv.w2sxir_p.requirements.txt'

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: It seems likely that the root user owns the directory.  Can you `RUN conda ...` in your Dockerfile, so that the environment is part of the image and doesn't need to be recreated every time you run a new container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried this, but I get exactly the same error

Comment: I have found a solution: I have put RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sudo chmod -R a+rwx /home/latplan"] just after the COPY . /home/latplan, but it's a very ugly solution

Comment: Do you need to `RUN chown` the directory to a different user; or `COPY --chown=...` some other user; or switch to `USER root` before you `RUN conda env create`?  If you run `id` (or `docker run --rm your-image id`), what user are you?

Comment: @DavidMaze if I run "id" I get test_user, which is the user created by default during this Docker installation. I am not sure I can run conda as root

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in the end, it revolved to unlock all permissions on the directory where the yml is situated.

```
FROM continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7

COPY . /home/latplan

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sudo chmod -R a+rw /home/latplan"] # Allowing all permissions on the directory where the .yml is situated, just for the install

RUN sudo apt-get update

RUN sudo apt-get install nano

WORKDIR /home/latplan

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "conda env create --name latplan -f environment.yml"]

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sudo chmod -R 755 /home/latplan"] # GOING BACK to 'normal' permissions

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "conda init bash"]
```

Comment: (`RUN command` is the same as `RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "command"]`; prefer the shorter form.)